# Maintaining Node.js sessions between multiple instances on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, queue

I have 3 instances of a Node.js worker role running on Windows Azure. I'm trying to maintain sessions between all the instances.

Azure Queue seems like the recommended approach, but how do I ensure all the instances receive the session, as the queue deletes the session once a single instance has de-queued it?

Azure table isn't really suitable for my application as the sessions are too frequent and need  not be stored for more than 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

A queue isn't a good mechanism for session state; it's for message-passing. And once one instance reads a queue message, it's no longer visible while a particular role instance is processing that message. Also: what would you do with the message when done with it? Update it and then make it visible again? The issue is that you cannot choose which "session" to read. It's an almost-FIFO queue (messages that aren't processed properly can reappear). It's not like a key/value store.

To create an accessible session repository, you can take advantage of Azure's in-role (or dedicated role) caching, which is a distributed cache across your role instances. You can use Table Storage too - just simple key/value type of reads/writes. And Table Storage is included in the node.js Azure SDK.

That said: let's go the cache route here. Since your sessions are short-lived, and (I'm guessing) don't take up too much memory, you can start with an in-role cache (the cache shares the worker role RAM with your node code, taking a percentage of memory). The cache is also memcache-compatible, which is easy to access from a node application.

If you take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16327843/272109), I show where caching is accessed. You'll need to set up the cache this way, but also set up the memcache server gateway by adding an internal endpoint called `memcache_default`. Then, point your memcache client class to the internal endpoint. Done.

The full instructions (and details around the memcache gateway vs. client shim, which you'd use when setting up a dedicated cache role) are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh914167.aspx). You'll see that the instructions are slightly different if using a dedicated cache, as it's then recommended to use a client shim in your node app's worker role.